# MikTex Problems on Mac

Tags: errors, miktex, mac

For about a month now my MikTex app isn't working on the Mac.  I think it was after ugrading the OS, but not sure.  My TexWorks wont access it when I try to run a LaTeX file, and I can't even open the MikTex console.  I get the attached errors:

"A MiKTeX configuration file could not be loaded."

Details:

"error="invalid value definition", line="6", file="/Users/danobrien/Library/Application Support/MiKTeX/texmfs/config/miktex/config/miktex.ini"

I haver tried reinstalling multiple times.  Same error.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The miktex issue tracker is here https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues. As an alternative you could also install texlive (mactex: https://www.tug.org/mactex/).

Comment: BTW, I have had 8 trouble free years on a mac.  This just randomly happened.

Comment: Which version of MacOS are you running at present?

Comment: I have the latest Mac OS